Sync multiple source folders with multiple destination folders
Can I sync folders A and B, with folders C and D?  (Maybe buckets or libraries is the correct term to use here?)
Current situation:

some contents of A might already be on C or D
some contents of B might already be on C or D

The task:
Whatever contents of A and B are not present on C or D need to be copied to either C or D, doesn't matter where.  (I suppose whichever destination SD card has the proper free space available.)
Context: I'm trying to synchronize multiple music file folders (A:\Music, B:\Music, etc.) with multiple SD cards (C:\Music, D:\Music, etc.).
Again it doesn't matter what goes where, just as long as everything goes somewhere.
Currently I have access to:

TeraCopy
FreeFileSync
Command Prompt (robocopy, xcopy, etc.)

I don't mind purchasing reasonably priced software that can accomplish this task.
Thanks!

I believe that your logic will require code, even if it is nothing more than script.  You will need something to catalog everything already on the SD cards first, then catalog everything in the machine-side folders.  The paths will need to be trimmed to just filename and compared.  All duplicates removed.  Copy the remaining files from the list to first free drive.

In case it helps/matters, most of the files (80+%) are already on one of the SD cards.  It's the new ~20% files that need to be placed systematically, like I described.

Do you suggest using robocopy/xcopy for using such a script?

Could I do the script you're suggesting with a simple DOS batch (.BAT) file you think?  Or something more intensive will be needed?

Those tools aren't smart enough to know that A: B: C: logic.  Batch could do it.  Powershell.. just about anything.  ChatGPT can often make something useful or even give a start.  Sometimes it produces smelly fecal matter.

You could merge C and D as one folder (say E), then use free file sync to update A and B to E, then split E to 2 chunks. Fill C until its full, and put the rest on D for example.

If you're going for a script, you could do it as follows. If A and B contains all files, erase C and D. Then loop through all files in A and B and copy them to C. If it fails, copy it to D. If you sort the whole list of files from A and B by size, largest first, chances are highest that it will fill correctly.

A lot to think about!

One problem I run into with a lot of copying files back-and-forth: the files occasionally get corrupted and some unwanted noise shows up in the music files.  These are all my own CDs I have ripped long ago, mostly in FLAC, but I've seen the file corruption happen in all file formats.

In a past life I used to know PHP, Ruby, JavaScript, some C#, and basic DOS commands.  I haven't used them in years so they're all the same to me right now.  Can you suggest which language to go with so I can start researching the commands I will need?  And, just for knowledge, why do you prefer that particular programming language for this task?

LPChip: I like your solution for its simplicity.   Well done and thank you!
